# How to install mongodb 3.6 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Installing mongodb 3.6 on ubuntu 22 keeps throwing this error!!

```yaml
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I am new to ubuntu system but tried everything available in the internet.
also Downgraded the `libsssl1`
`sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Just curious ... Why do you want to install such an old version of MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB version 3.6 is [EOL since April 2021](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 3.6 is relatively old (EOL/EOS April 2021) and not recommended for production use unless the case requires it (the latest is 6.1 as of reading this text)

If you need it only for some testing to not pollute your Ubuntu 22 installation I would recommend to install it manually in some folder separate for your testing only, described in following steps:

1. Download the 3.6 package from the archive(example 3.6.22):

   ```
   https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-3.6.22.tgz
   ```
2. Uncompress the binary files in some folder ( example /database/bin ) .
3. If needed download the expected ssl libraries and extract the libcrypto package to expected location:

   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/

   sudo cp libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/
4. Prepare some nice config file and store in /database/bin/mydb.conf :

   ```
   storage:
    dbPath: /database/db1
    directoryPerDB: true
    journal:
      enabled: true
    wiredTiger:
      engineConfig:
        cacheSizeGB: 1
        directoryForIndexes: true

   systemLog:
     destination: file
     logAppend: true
     path: /database/log/db1.log

   net:
     port: 20000
     bindIp: 127.0.0.1


   processManagement:
     fork: true
   ```
5. Create the necessary directories and start the mongod binary:

   ```
   mkdir -p /database/db1
   mkdir -p /database/log 
   /database/bin/mongod --config mydb.conf
   ```
6. You can access the database as follow:

   ```
   /database/bin/mongo --port 20000
   ```

Comment: You can track  the tags for releases and release candidates in the 6.X series with `git ls-remote https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git 'r6.*'`.

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest stable version, issue the following

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

To get rid of "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
"
open the terminal with "Ctrl + Alt + T" and type:

```
sudo apt install --fix-missing
```

Hope that helps...